# How to sort dates of three columns and get rows of all these rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union, unpivot

I have a MySQL table like this.

```
    |------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    | NAME               |  DateType   |    date1    |     date2    |     date3    |
    |------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    | Joe Bloggs         |  d1         |  21-09-2020 |  00-00-0000  |  00-00-0000  |
    | Bob Bobbing        |  d3         |  00-00-0000 |  23-11-2020  |  21-09-2010  |
    | etc... ----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

What I want is, to merge these dates, sort them and get results like this:

```
|-------------------------------------------------|
| NAME               |  DateType   |    date      |
|-------------------------------------------------|
| Joe Bloggs         |  d1         |  21-09-2020  |
| Bob Bobbing        |  d3         |  23-11-2020  |
| Bob Bobbing        |  d3         |  21-09-2010  |
| etc... -----------------------------------------|
```

Or something like this, getting column name:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| NAME               |  DateType   |   column     |    date      |
|-------------------------------------------------|--------------|
| Joe Bloggs         |  d1         |   date1      |  21-09-2020  |
| Bob Bobbing        |  d2         |   date2      |  23-11-2020  |
| Bob Bobbing        |  d3         |   date3      |  21-09-2010  |
| etc... --------------------------------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to unpivot the column to rows, while filtering out all-`0` dates. In MySQL, the best option probably is `union all`:

```
select name, datetype, 'date1' which_col, date1 as date from mytable where date1 > '0000-00-00'
union all select name, datetype, 'date2', date2 from mytable where date2 > '0000-00-00'
union all select name, datetype, 'date', date3 from mytable where date3 > '0000-00-00'
order by name, datetype, date
```

Comment: Compare with zero date may give strange result... it is better to compare with some legal date value below the least logically correct for the data but in allowed values range for column's datatype.

Comment: how can I get the column name? (I have edited the question)

Comment: @SandeepKumar: you can add a column with fixed values in each `union` member. I edited my answer.